# Change owner of folder on read-only drive in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, hfs, read-only, chown

My IMac died (power supply issue, out of warranty) and I removed the HDD so I could recover some files.  I'm trying to copy files from my Desktop folder on the Mac HDD using Ubuntu 10.04 (running from the CD-ROM), but I get access denied errors when I try to `cd` or `ls` into the directory because I'm not the owner.

I tried running `chown -R Desktop` but I get an error saying that the file system is read-only.

Is there some way I can make the drive read/write or access the files without changing the owner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The write support for some foreign filesystems in Linux is buggy so turned off by default. This may be why your Mac filesystem was mounted read-only.

If this is a one-off data recovery, just do it as root.

---

For some filesystems, you can specify that everything should be world-readable, or that every file should be owned by a particular user. First determine the volume and mount point of the Mac filesystem with the command `df .` in the `Desktop` directory; this displays something like

```
/dev/sdb4   123456  78901  23456  42%   /media/disk1
```

Make sure no process is using the Mac filesystem (this includes any shell that has its working directory on it), and run

```
umount /media/disk1
mount -o umask=022 /dev/sdb4 /media/disk1
```

`umask=022` means that everyone can read everything. You could also use `uid=ktrauberman` (replace `ktrauberman` by your user name) so that every file is owned by you.

Comment: How do I switch to the root user while running from the live CD?  I tried running the commands using `sudo`, but I encountered the same errors.

Comment: @ktrauberman: Do you mean that `sudo ls /media/disk1/path/to/Desktop` fails? If so, could you add to your question the output of `sudo ls -ld /media/disk1 /media/disk1/path /media/disk1/path/to /media/disk/path/to/Desktop` (substitute the names as appropriate of course)? And please also copy-paste the error messages.

Comment: Hmm. Now that I think about it, I don't think I tried `sudo` with `ls` or `cd`. I will try this tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I was able to `sudo ls` into the locked directory and then `sudo cp` the files out of it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try unmounting the filesystem and then remounting it from the command line with the -w option

something like

> mount -w /dev/sbd4 /mnt/macdrive